# Firebase Realtime - Deleting a node that does not exist does not fail

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to delete nodes in realtime. The following call works perfectly (Node.js, I'm using this on functions):

```
admin.database().ref(path).remove()
```

However... it returns OK (null if I make the callback) regardless of whether the node to delete exists or not.

**My question:** is there any way for the remove to fail if the node to delete does not exist? I want to avoid reading before deleting.

Thank you.

Comment: delete() is working as expected.  If you want to know if the node exists before deleting it, you will have to read it first, or use a transaction to conditionally do something if it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behavior: deleting a non-existing node is a null operation that always succeeds.

If you want to check if a node exists and delete it, you should [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions).